# Find first class then gradually add class to all divs with same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a selection of dots which I'm making from a table like the below:

```
<div class="steps-wrapper">
    <table class="steps">
        <tbody>
            <tr>

                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="active"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="active"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="active"></td>
                <td class="active"></td>
                <td class="active"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="active"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="active"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**[Here is a fiddle to view aswell.](https://jsfiddle.net/mmxrfzqy/)**

I would like it so that when the `td`'s are visible they gradually load in. 
So I would find the first `td` with the class active and fade it in. It would then find the next `td` with the class active and fade that in 0.2s after the last one and so on.

Looking at the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmxrfzqy/) the first dot to load in would be top right and then it would gradually load in from the right, across and down to bottom left. However the shape of the dots will change so sometimes it could load from top left down to bottom right.

This is my jQuery so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(function($, win) {
  $.fn.inViewport = function(cb) {
     return this.each(function(i,el){
       function visPx(){
         var H = $(this).height(),
             r = el.getBoundingClientRect(), t=r.top, b=r.bottom;
         return cb.call(el, Math.max(0, t>0? H-t : (b<H?b:H)));  
       } visPx();
       $(win).on("resize scroll", visPx);
     });
  };
}(jQuery, window));

$(".steps-wrapper").inViewport(function(px){
    if(px) $('td.active').addClass("o-fade-in");
});

});
```

I'm not sure how to make each individual dot load in. Im currently loading in all the td's at the same time when visible.

---

**Update:**
The animation now works perfectly. However if one `.steps-wrapper` is activated it then activates all on the page. How can I make it so that other dots on the page dont animate until they are seen in the viewport just like the first one?

[Here is a new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmxrfzqy/3/) showing the issue.

Comment: why the high white div that says scroll down ? do you want the dots to load according to your scrolling ? or as soon as the page loads, they gradually fades in ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I have made a few changes to your code in order to work the way you want:

**1.** Make your table dots `rtl` that way when we apply the class will get from right to left:

```
.steps {
  direction:rtl;
}
```

<sub>Also check the markup for the table on the fiddle</sub>

**2.** Adding the fade effect with `transition`:

```
.steps td {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  /*Add this*/
  transition:2s linear;
}
```

**3.** Add the class one at time:

```
$(".steps-wrapper").inViewport(function(px){
    if(px) fadeDots()
});

function fadeDots() {
  var i = 0;
  setInterval(function(){
    $('td.active').eq(i).addClass('o-fade-in');
    i++
  },100)
}
```

### [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mmxrfzqy/1/)

---

**Edit::**

After testing I see that the `setInterval` keeps running and can mess up your performance so also we can check when all dots are visible and then stop the interval:

```
function fadeDots() {
  var i = 0,
      l = $('td.active').length;

  var m = setInterval(function(){
      $('td.active').eq(i).addClass('o-fade-in');
      i++
      if(i == l) {
        clearInterval(m);
      }
  },100)
}
```

#### [NewFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmxrfzqy/2/)

Comment: Glad to help U @probablybest

Comment: wondering if you could help me with my updated question? I'm having an issue with dots on the rest of the page triggering when the first one is seen in the viewport. I only want each set of dots to activate when visible in the viewport.

Comment: Yep you can pass the actual element as reference on the function ... https://jsfiddle.net/mmxrfzqy/4/ @probablybest . Next time avoid updates like that on your answered quests it's better to make a new one and keep this clear. And if you want you can refer me to that :)